# Django: 404.html exists but 500.html is used

Tags: django, django-templates

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/slug/`

With `Debug=True` I get `Page not found (404) - No entry found matching the query`. With `Debug=False` I get shown the `projectName/templates/500.html` instead of `404.html`.

Both look exactly the same. `500.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}server error{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Error 500: server error</h3>

{% endblock %}
```

`404.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}page not found{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Error 404: page not found</h3>

{% endblock %}
```

Why does Django load 500 instead of 404 although it exists? It cannot be a template error.

Comment: what's your django version?,if you use django1.5 and Debug=False,you must add `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings`  more details:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: Yes, I am using django 1.5. I tried `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/', 'localhost']` but it still raises the 500 error when trying it locally.

Comment: I figured it out. This one works: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']`

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure that you've correctly set up ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings, chances are your 404.html template is somehow not correct. There might be a syntax error (or it can't find the base template), which, in turn, causes a new 500 exception to be raised.

Try simplifying your 404.html by only including static HTML.