# Django1.5 : Trying to Custom 404.html page instead getting the 500

Tags: django

I'm trying to create the custom 404.html page for the `HTTP 404` error.

For this url `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/Books/dsfdsf/` it is showing the `Page not found (404)` default debugging page, while `DEBUG=True`.
For same url i want to create custom 404 page.

i have gone through the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view) for this.

Following steps i have taken:

1). `DEBUG=False` in **settings.py**

2). `handler404 = 'pollsite.views.custom_404'` in **urls.py**

3). **views.py**

```
def custom_404(request):
    return render('404.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

4). i have placed the `404.html`file in template directory , `TEMPLATE_DIRS`

now i expect the custom error page `404.html` to appear when i tries to access  127.0.0.1:8000/polls/Books/dsfdsf, right?
Instead i'm getting the `TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html`

Even valid url showing the  `TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html`

Why it is not  generating HTTP 404 error, and thereby invoking custom `404.html` file ?

I tried solution mentioned for [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382318/django-renders-the-template-500-html-instead-of-404-html), and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921753/django-404-html-exists-but-500-html-is-used)
but still geting annoying error `TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html`

please point out what is the issue?

**EDIT**: stacktarce of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

.........................**Solution:**

1) in **settings.py** set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']`

2) in **views.py** `return render_to_response('404.html')`

Comment: It sounds like your app is actually throwing a 500 error but can't find a template for the 500 error. Have you checked your logs to see what the error is?

Comment: i have edited my post for error i'm getting

Comment: Yes, the error is that because you have `DEBUG=False`, an error it being thrown but there is no 500 template in your `templates` folder. You need to add a `500.html` there just like you have the `404.html`. That won't solve your problem though as there is likely an error in your setup causing the 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.py there is a setting:

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

If `Debug = False` then Django looks at `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.  This setting needs to contain your IP address.  You can also set it to:

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This works fine in the development environment, but should not be used in production.  This is most likely your issue and why Django is throwing a `500.html` server error when trying to load that page.